# Data method in JQuery

Tags: jquery

In my code I want to send two parameters in my data. `Name` is one of my parameter names and its value is in a variable `a`. Another parameter name is `type` with the value in the `str` variable. The following did not work for me:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./server",
  data: "name="+a+"type="+str,

      success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: data : JSON.stringify( { name : a, type = str } ),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./server",
  data: "name="+a+"&type="+str,

      success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
})
```

Just like querystrings. Remember to proper URL Encode them though. Like PHP's [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode), only, in JavaScript (look at escape(), however that one is not a full implementation either).

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./server",
  data: {name:a, type: str},

      success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
})
```

with literals instead of variables it would be like this:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./server",
  data: {name: "some name", type: "some type"},

      success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
})
```

Comment: i want to insert the variable in that data 
data: {name:a, type: str},
where a and str are my variable ..But its not working..Suggest me

Comment: The data is not a string it's a javascript / json object. So you don't need to concatenate anything - just type it as shown with the {} brackets and the : instead of = and it should work ok.